# Set up nginx successfully on Ubuntu server on vultr but can't see nginx welcome page on browser

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, vultr

I have followed step by step this article (https://coderrocketfuel.com/article/how-to-set-up-nginx-on-a-ubuntu-server-with-vultr) to set up an instance on Vultr and everything went smoothly and fine but at the end of the second step, where the articles says "visit http://server_domain_or_IP" and you should see the nginx welcome page, I go to http://my_server_ip_address, and I always get "The connection has timed out" screen on browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Need to open a firewall port on your server?

```
sudo ufw allow http
```

and/or

```
sudo ufw allow https
```

Comment: thank you for this answer - it solved my problem. I'm new and not allowed to upvote so I'm writing it here.